# AndEngine analog and areatouched problems?

Tags: android, button, andengine, area

I am using AndEngine GLES 2.0 and well I've been reading a lot in search for an answer but I just can't find anything... what happens is that I am doing a game and I have `AnalogOnScreenControl` on the left side of the screen, and 2 `onAreaTouched` "buttons", so when I am using the analog and move the finger all the way to any "button", when I lift my finger, the analog is still "moving" as if I still had my finger on the screen... So is there any way to prevent this? like setting an area of response for the analog? I don't know if I explained myself well... but any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: what code do you have?  this sounds stupid, but are you processing the event generated when the user takes their finger off the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable Multi touch:

in your `onCreateEngineOptions()` add : `options.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch( true );`

Now when you have your finger on the joystick and press a button with another finger, it will reference a different pointerID.